# Backup lights, monitor and alarm sometimes don't work when backing up

Tags: transmission, electronics

When I switch the stick to R on my automatic gear, the backup lights, monitor and alarm sometimes don't work, sometimes do. It feels as if it's random when there's current in the wires.

When they don't, I shift the stick up and down multiple times until they work, but sometimes it doesn't help as well.

At the repair shop they said it's on the transmission itself, but I find it pretty weird.

Sorry for my English by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the make and model of your vehicle, the reverse light switch and the other features dependent on that switch, can be out of position in such a way as to prevent the light from working. It's not completely inaccurate to suggest that it's "on" your transmission, as some reverse switches are mounted to the housing, while others can be integrated into the housing.

Perhaps you can locate a service manual specific to your vehicle and examine the diagram for the transmission and/or reverse electrical circuit to locate the reverse light switch. If it's external, you may be able to adjust/tighten any loose component and restore your features.